# OPENJSON to find one data point in Single JSON Array Column data

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

I have a table called InboundLog that has 5 columns - one specific column (Inbound_data) contains a JSON array - I am attempting to query for a specific item in this column - ssn=77755777 (Not real data)

My current query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
OPENJSON(InboundLog, Inbound_data.patient) 
WITH (Inbound_data.demographics.ssn = 77755777)
```

```
TABLE: InboundLog
TABLE COLUMN: Inbound_data (JSON Array Data)
{"patient": 
    {"identifiers": 
        [{"id": "5265635341",
          "idType": "Pancakes EMR"}],
           
          "demographics": 
            {"firstName": "Spider",
             "lastName": "Man",
             "dob": "1930-01-06",
             "ssn": "777557777",
             "gender": "Male",
             "phone": "+18088675302",
             "email": "test1@example.com",

           "address": 
            {"street1": "4762 Apple Street",
             "street2": "",
             "city": "Monroe",
             "state": "WI",
             "zip": "53566"},

           "diagnoses": 
            [{"codeType": "icd10Code",
              "code": "A01.00","isPrimary": false},
             {"codeType": "icd10Code",
              "code": "W56.01XA","isPrimary": true}],

           "allergies": 
            [{ "description": "smoke" },
             { "description": "no allergy" }]
            }
    }
}
```

I am doing something wrong here, but I can't figure out what

Comment: there no such record ion your example

Comment: OK - I edited this because I recognize that my original question was not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code returns the following error message because it's not invoking [`OPENJSON()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) correctly:

```
Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Try using `OPENJSON()` in a `cross apply` such as the following...

```sql
-- Setup test data...
create table dbo.InboundLog (
  ID int not null identity(1,1),
  Inbound_Data nvarchar(max)
);
insert dbo.InboundLog (Inbound_Data) values
  (N'{"patient": { "demographics": { "ssn": "111111111 "} } }'),
  (N'{"patient": { "demographics": { "ssn": "222222222 "} } }'),
  (N'{"patient": { "demographics": { "ssn": "333333333 "} } }'),
  (N'{"patient": { "demographics": { "ssn": "444444444 "} } }'),
  (N'{"patient": { "demographics": { "ssn": "555555555 "} } }'),
  (N'{"patient": { "demographics": { "ssn": "666666666 "} } }'),
  (N'{
    "patient": {
        "identifiers": [
            {
                "id": "5265635341",
                "idType": "Pancakes EMR"
            }
        ],
        "demographics": {
            "firstName": "Spider",
            "lastName": "Man",
            "dob": "1930-01-06",
            "ssn": "777557777",
            "gender": "Male",
            "phone": "+18088675302",
            "email": "test1@example.com",
            "address": {
                "street1": "4762 Apple Street",
                "street2": "",
                "city": "Monroe",
                "state": "WI",
                "zip": "53566"
            },
            "diagnoses": [
                {
                    "codeType": "icd10Code",
                    "code": "A01.00",
                    "isPrimary": false
                },
                {
                    "codeType": "icd10Code",
                    "code": "W56.01XA",
                    "isPrimary": true
                }
            ],
            "allergies": [
                {
                    "description": "smoke"
                },
                {
                    "description": "no allergy"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}');

-- Display the SSN values contained in records (alternative 1)...
select ID, SSN
from InboundLog
cross apply openjson(Inbound_data, N'$.patient.demographics') with (
  SSN varchar(10) '$.ssn'
);

/*
-- Returns:
ID  SSN
--- ----------
1   111111111 
2   222222222 
3   333333333 
4   444444444 
5   555555555 
6   666666666 
7   777557777
*/

-- Display the SSN values contained in records (alternative 2)...
select ID, SSN
from InboundLog
cross apply openjson(Inbound_data) with (
  SSN varchar(10) N'$.patient.demographics.ssn'
);

/*
--Returns same data as alternative 1.
*/

-- Select a record with a specific SSN value...
select IL.*
from InboundLog IL
cross apply openjson(Inbound_data) with (
  SSN varchar(10) N'$.patient.demographics.ssn'
)
where SSN = '777557777';
```

Note that, as with XPaths in XML, the object paths in JSON are case-sensitive so `'$.SSN'` is different than `'$.ssn'`.